# Help. How can I have a plain track to two different planes

Tags: rigging

I've been trying to create a setup with three planes. When one of them moves on the z axis, the center plane should look towards it on the y axis. When the other one moves on the z axis, the center plane should look towards it on the x axis. Here is an animation of what i'm trying to achieve. Does anyone know how to do this,[image]

Comment: It takes drivers.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome.  Please see below article on Drivers.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/introduction.html

[image: driver]

In this animation, I have the Drivers panel open at the bottom.  Good Luck!